# Plotting Large Datasets in IPython Notebook (Bokeh)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, bokeh

I have a large dataset that I would like to plot in an IPython notebook.

I read the ~0.5GB .csv file into a Pandas `DataFrame` using `read_csv`, this takes about two minutes.  Then I try to plot this data.

```
data = pd.read_csv('large.csv')
output_notebook()
p1 = figure()
p1.circle(data.index, data['myDataset'])
show(p1)
```

My browser spins and does not show me any plots.  I have tried the following:

1. `output_file()` instead of `output_notebook()`
2. Graphing using a `ColumnSource` object as the `source` argument to `circle()`
3. Downsampling my data to something more manageable.

Bokeh claims on its website to offer "high-performance interactivity over very large or streaming datasets".  How do I visualize these large datasets without my computer grinding to a halt?

Answer (score 10):

The question is too broad to offer any specific code suggestions. I would be curious what the size of the downsampling you tried was. The default HTML Canvas for Bokeh can definitely accommodate tens of thousands of circles. There are a few options:

- for simple scatters and lines of hundreds of thousands of points, there is a WebGL backend that may be useful.

  http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/webgl.html
- using the Bokeh Server, create a Bokeh app to downsample the data before rendering it. There are some app examples here:

  https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app
- The [DataShader](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader) library can be used to perform downsampling of large data sets (hundreds of millions to billions of points), and integrates very well with Bokeh.

Comment: Hello @bigreddot could you please have look this question of mine, I am really struggling to get the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207525/how-to-generate-multiple-plots-by-clicking-a-single-plot-for-more-infomation-usi

Comment: That question appears to be about Matplotlib, not about Bokeh. I am afraid I  don't know much about Matplotlib at all.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, in Bokeh could I achieve my requirement?

Comment: I'm afraid the link above to your question no longer work, so I can't say.